# Como referenciar uma imagem tag <img>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou estudando Asp.Net MVC e estou com dificuldades para definir a URL da tag

HTML:

```
      <!-- menu profile quick info -->
            <div class="profile">
                <div class="profile_pic">
                    <img src="~/Views/Home/images/img.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
                </div>
                <div class="profile_info">
                    <span>Welcome,</span>
                    <h2>John Doe</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Minha duvida é, esta certo essa URL: `src="~/Views/Home/images/img.jpg"`?

Minha hierarquia do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pois, ao executar, estou tendo o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já deve ter notado que dentro da pasta **Views** há um arquivo *web.config*.

Por padrão, este config restringe o acesso a todos os arquivos nesta pasta.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Com certeza você pode mudar isso, mas não faz sentido. Você pode acabar permitindo com que qualquer pessoa (bem ou mal intecionada) tenha acesso aos arquivos das Views.

A dica que eu te dou é colocar suas imagens em subpastas na pasta **Content**, e usá-las com o caminho **~/Content/Imagens/Home/img1.png**. Claro que você tem a opção de criar outras pastas também, mas acho que a Content já serve pra isso.